# android.content.SharedPreferences' getString(key, defValue) method behaves not as expected

Tags: android

I'm new to Android and have been trying out Yamba, a microblog client on Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10) emulator. As we know, a microblog like twitter has a timeline but won't fetch updates without the user's username and password. Thus, in the onCreate() method of the TimelineActivity (main entry point) I have the following codes:

```
 if (yamba.getPrefs().getString("username", null) == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PrefsActivity.class));
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msgSetupPrefs, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

the `getprefs()` method will get a SharedPreferences object, and here's the doc for getString

```
 public abstract String getString (String key, String defValue)
 Since: API Level 1
 Retrieve a String value from the preferences.

 Parameters
 key    The name of the preference to retrieve.
 defValue   Value to return if this preference does not exist.
 Returns    Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. 
 Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not a String.
```

However, this is not the case. If the username is blank the getString method will return an empty string ("") rather than the "defValue" defined as above. After I change second (null) to (""), it works with the preference view being showed first when a user launch the app. So why doesn't the method behave as the doc says?

Comment: What did the method return when you changed to ("")?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify it that I change the second null to "" and now codes in the if-block will be executed

Answer (score 2):

When you say "if the username is blank", do you mean it has already been inserted into the prefs with no value, or it has never been set? The defValue is the value returned in the event that there is no matching key in the prefs file. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, I do have set the default username and password and they are both null

Comment: That makes sense. Keep in mind that a shared preference is basically just a text file approach to storing thing. It doesn't have a concept of a null. You are just getting an empty string with getString. To get null you would need to have never inserted anything with a key of "username", or first called edit.remove("username");

Comment: Sorry, I debugged it again and found the default values hadn't been set yet then. The keys are set in an xml file.

Comment: This probably means they are all set in advance right?  Is there a reason you want the value returned to be null instead of ""?

Comment: Yeah, only the keys so the values are undefined then but I have no idea about the default values the system may set.

Comment: Actually, it's sample codes from a book and now I know null won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `yamba.getPrefs().getString("username", null).equals("")` 
The shared preference method should be working for your case

Comment: Yeah, but `.equals()` works best with Strings. `==` is sometimes unreliable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch both null and empty strings append .length()

```
(someobject.getMethod().length() == 0)
```

Comment: I think not that you could invoke any methods on a null string which  may throw a NullPointerException